# Como puedo mejorar esta consulta para que su rendimiento sea mejor o redundante SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente tengo esta consulta

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE @CodRef varchar(20);
   SELECT @CodRef= CodReferido FROM Freelancer.Usuario WHERE Idu_free = 
   '561DADE';

 select Usuario, Referido from Freelancer.Usuario WHERE Referido = @CodRef
END
```

La idea de esta consulta es mostrar los Referidos de un Freelancer por su Codigo de Referido. Para saber de que Freelancer se mostraran los referido se recibe el id principal del Freelancer.

Se tiene en cuenta que es una sola tabla solo que si un Usuario es Referido de un Freelancer se le añade el codigo de este en la Columna Referido entendiendo que el campo que tiene esta columna pertenecer al codigo de referido del Freelancer principal.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda aceptar la respuesta que te sirivio!!!

Answer (score 4):

Esto se puede hacer con un self join:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT
        u2.Usuario,
        u2.Referido
    FROM Freelancer.Usuario u1
    JOIN Freelancer.Usuario u2
        ON u1.CodReferido = u2.Referido
    WHERE u1.Idu_free = '561DADE'
    ;
END
```

Comment: perfecto..... mil gracias es justamente lo necesario. Agradezco tu tiempo y atención, bendiciones.

Comment: estoy tenuedo un problema ahora cuando realizo la consulta con una Tabla adicional me muestra el mismo registro repetido si coloco distinct solo me muestra uno donde tengo registro en el cual se resultado en algunos casos deberian ser dos o mas registros no uno solo

Comment: @AlexGC si esta respuesta te sirvió para resolver el problema, márcala como aceptada para que la publicación quede completa. Para más información, visita el centro de ayuda y lee este par de artículos cortos [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) y [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @AlexGC es que agregar una "tabla adicional" es ya otro problema. No sé qué estás haciendo, cuál es la estructura de esa tabla, cómo la estás cruzando con el resto de la consulta, etc